# Why debug can display, but Release can not?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

1. MainPage.xaml
   `<Image x:Name="img1" />`

2.MainPage.xaml.cs

```
try 
{ 
    img1.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("IF_Rookie_Project.images.IF_ver2.png"); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{ 
    DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message.ToString(), "OK"); 
}
```

As title. Why debug can display, but Release cannot?

Comment: Have you configured the PNG to be written to the output folder?

Comment: What do you mean about the release? What platform are you developing on iOS, Android or UWP?

Comment: Land Lu - MSFT  uwp

Comment: @lihu30316 Could you please share a sample? I haven't encountered this situation before.